# how to finish activity after picture taken by camera

Tags: android

I am using an activity to capture image
i want to start a finish my activity on picture taken
on capture button i write following code

```
btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback,
                        jpegCallback);
                CameraActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
```

but my activity is not responding after adding

CameraActivity.this.finish()

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

release any camera object and save a variable with datatype activity in the class.. call finish from that variable.